# How can I find out if my computer is able to run Client Hyper-V in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v, requirements

I want to try [Client Hyper-V](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857623.aspx) out in Windows 8.  How do I find out if my computer is capable of running it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check whether your computer meets the system requirements for Client Hyper-V is Windows 8, type the following at a CMD or PowerShell prompt:

```
systeminfo
```

At the bottom of the output you will see something like this:

```
Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: No
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: No
                           Second Level Address Translation: No
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

In the example above you can see that the machine I am using is not capable of running Client Hyper-V.

Additionally, from the [Microsoft website](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857623.aspx):

> Hyper-V requires a 64-bit system that has Second Level Address
>   Translation (SLAT). For information about checking and changing the
>   virtualization support settings of your system BIOS, consult your
>   system manufacturer.
>
> Hyper-V supports the creation of both 32-bit and 64-bit operating
>   systems in virtual machines.
>
> Note You must license each of the virtual machine operating systems
>   according to their requirements. 4 GB of RAM is required. The RAM on
>   your computer running Client Hyper-V is allocated and deallocated
>   dynamically as required by the virtual machines. You can run several
>   virtual machines on a computer running Client Hyper-V (also called a
>   “host”) that has the minimum 4 GB of RAM, but you will need additional
>   RAM for 5 or more virtual machines, depending on the RAM requirements
>   for each virtual machine.
>
> Client Hyper-V supports the same storage migration capability that is
>   included in Hyper-V in Windows Server 2012. This means you can have
>   your virtual machines fairly independent of the underlying storage.
>   You can move a virtual machine’s storage to and from one local drive
>   to another, to a USB drive, or to a remote file share without needing
>   to stop the virtual machine.

Comment: That last paragraph describes quite an amazing new feature of Hyper-V, which even VMware vSphere currently lacks.